# Caffe lDBM Model - two files missing

Tags: caffe

I'm currently working on a face recognition project.
We found a caffe model to classify age.
(Apparent age estimation trained on LAP dataset)
https://data.vision.ee.ethz.ch/cvl/rrothe/imdb-wiki/

We would like to use that model to classify images but there are two files missing which are required by caffe.
A ".binaryproto" file and a "synset_words.txt".

Do someone know where we can get them from without training the model ourself?

Comment: Is there no name for the binaryproto file?  The main use I've seen for this format is to hold image set mean values, subtracted to normalize the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model requires us to subtract the image mean from each image, so we have to compute the mean. `/caffe/tools/compute_image_mean.cpp` implements that. which will make `/path/imagenet_mean.binaryproto`.

the `synset_words.txt` contain sorted synset names in their ASCII order, and then label them (for example in `imagenet` from 0 to 999) - create it via your dataset.